# How to write groups of numbers using Console.Write?

Tags: c#, arraylist

I'm very new to C# (And Stack Overflow, forgive me for any poor etiquette here), and I'm writing the game Mastermind in a console application. I'm trying to show a list of the user's guesses at the end of the game, and I know that using Console.WriteLine(); will just give me 30-odd lines off numbers which don't tell the user anything.

How can I alter my code so that the program displays 4 numbers in a group, at a time? For example:

1234

1234

1234

```
//Store numbers in a history list
ArrayList guesses = new ArrayList(); //This is the ArrayList

Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first guess.");
guess1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
guesses.Add(guess1);

foreach (int i in guesses)
{
    Console.Write(i);
}
```

Comment: ok question where are you adding the contents to the ArraList..?? where is the code where you are capturing the end users input Console.Read();....?????

Comment: In a series of Console.WriteLines(); after the arraylist has been declared, I'll edit my code ^^upthere now.

Comment: so what you want is 4 guesses on a line, then skip to the next line?  Do you want any spacing between the guesses?

Comment: No, just a list of guesses made by the user, in groups of 4.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that each element of your byte array is a single digit (0-9). If that assumption is invalid -- please let me know, I'll modify the code :)

```
Action<IEnumerable<int>> dump = null;

dump = items =>
            {
                if(items.Any())
                {
                  var head = String.Join("", items.Take(4));
                  Console.WriteLine(head);
                  var tail = items.Skip(4);
                  dump(tail);
                }
            };

dump(guesses);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're most of the way there, you have a console write that writes them all out without linebreaks.  Next add an integer `count` and set it to zero.  Increment it by one in the foreach loop.  `count % 4 == 0` will then be true for all counts that are a multiple of four.  This means you can stick an if block there with a write-line to give you your groups of four.

Answer (score 0):

This is some thing I quickly put together:

**Update:**

```
ArrayList guesses = new ArrayList(); //This is the ArrayList
    // Four or more
    guesses.Add(1); guesses.Add(2);
    guesses.Add(3);guesses.Add(4);
    guesses.Add(5); guesses.Add(6); guesses.Add(7);guesses.Add(8); guesses.Add(9);
    //Uncomment-Me for less than four inputs
    //guesses.Add(1); guesses.Add(2);
    int position = 0;
    if (guesses.Count < 4)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < guesses.Count; y++)
        {
            Console.Out.Write(guesses[y]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= guesses.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i%4 == 0)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", guesses[i - 4], guesses[i - 3],
                                                    guesses[i - 2], guesses[i - 1]));
                position = i;
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == guesses.Count)
                {
                    for (int j = position; j < i; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Out.Write(guesses[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Having given this answer if you have numbers higher than a single difit then it woule be a good idea to seperate them via a delimiter. So a comma or some thing, so its readble upon output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> endResult = new List<int>();
StringBuilder tempSb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i < groups.Count; i++)
{
    if(i % 4 == 0) {
        endResult.Add(int.Parse(sb.ToString()));
        tempSb.Clear(); // remove what was already added
    }
    tempSb.Append(group[i]);
}
// check to make sure there aren't any stragglers left in
// the StringBuilder. Would happen if the count of groups is not a multiple of 4
if(groups.Count % 4 != 0) {
    groups.Add(int.Parse(sb.ToString()));
}
```

This will give you a list of 4 digit ints and make sure you don't lose any if your the number of ints in your groups list is not a multiple of 4. Please note that I am continuing based on what you provided, so groups is the ArrayList of ints.